# how to analyze time-series data as a function of the time of day in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Suppose I have a random sample of data collected every 1 minute for a month.  Then suppose I want to use `pandas` to analyze this data as a function of the time of day, and see the differences between a weekend and weekday.  I can do this in `pandas` if my index is a `DateTimeIndex` by calculating the time of day as a 0-1 decimal value, manually binning the results in intervals of 10 minutes (or whatever) and then plotting the results using the `bins` column to actually calculate averages over the time intervals of the day, and then manually setting my tick positions and labels into something understandable.

However, this feels a little bit hacky and I am wondering if there are built-in pandas functions to achieve this same kind of analysis.  I haven't been able to find them so far.

```
dates = pd.date_range(start='2018-10-01', end='2018-11-01', freq='min')
vals = np.random.rand(len(dates))
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'dates': dates, 'vals': vals})
df.set_index('dates', inplace=True)

# set up a column to make the time of day a value from 0 to 1
df['day_fraction'] = (df.index.hour + df.index.minute / 60) / 24

# bin the time of day to analyze data during 10 minute intervals
df['day_bins'] = df['day_fraction'] - df['day_fraction'] % (1 / 24 / 6)

ax = df.plot('day_fraction', 'vals', marker='o', color='pink', alpha=0.05, label='')
df.groupby('day_bins')['vals'].mean().plot(ax=ax, label='average')
df[df.index.weekday < 5].groupby('day_bins')['vals'].mean().plot(ax=ax, label='weekday average')
df[df.index.weekday >= 5].groupby('day_bins')['vals'].mean().plot(ax=ax, label='weekend average')

xlabels = [label if label else 12 for label in [i % 12 for i in range(0, 25, 2)]]
xticks = [i / 24 for i in range(0, 25, 2)]
ax.set_xticks(xticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels)
ax.set_xlabel('time of day')
ax.legend()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need to use `groupby` with a lot of the built in `.dt` accessors. Group based on weekday or weekend and then form bins every 10 minutes (with `.floor`) and calculate the mean.

#### Setup

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates = pd.date_range(start='2018-10-01', end='2018-11-01', freq='min')
vals = np.random.rand(len(dates))
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'dates': dates, 'vals': vals})
df.set_index('dates', inplace=True)
```

#### Plot

```
df1 = (df.groupby([np.where(df.index.weekday < 5, 'weekday', 'weekend'),
                   df.index.floor('10min').time])
         .mean()
         .rename(columns={'vals': 'average'}))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,7))
df1.unstack(0).plot(ax=ax)  
# Plot Full Average
df.groupby(df.index.floor('10min').time).mean().rename(columns={'vals': 'average'}).plot(ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image]